# Get to a Folder in the Root of my Project - ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, system.io.directory

I have a root folder called `TestLogging` that contains a solution.  I have a console app, which has its own directory, and a test project which also has its own directory.

In Windows explorer I have manually created a directory called Configuration in the root folder `TestLogging`, which has an `xml` file named `Configuration.config`.

I am trying to get to this path via code to reference this file, without having to use an absolute path to this.

I have tried variations of examples from here using `System.IO` and they all point to the build directory of the current project that is being run e.g. `MyConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1`

Here are some of the things I've tried:

```
string defaultPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

// this does the same as above!
string pathToConsoleApp = Path.GetFullPath(AppContext.BaseDirectory);

// very similar to the other two!
var projectPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)));
```

Appoligies in advanced if this has been duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

```
string configpPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName, "Configuration.config.xml");
```

### Test code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string defaultPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        // this does the same as above!
        string pathToConsoleApp = Path.GetFullPath(AppContext.BaseDirectory);

        // very similar to the other two!
        var projectPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)));

        string configpPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName, "Configuration.config.xml");


        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.WriteLine("defaultPath:   " + defaultPath);
        Console.WriteLine("pathToConsoleApp:   " + pathToConsoleApp);
        Console.WriteLine("projectPath:   " + projectPath);
        Console.WriteLine("configpPath:   " + configpPath);
    }
}
```

### Test result

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I‘m not sure this will work.  Apologies as I don’t think I put enough emphasis on the Test project. This is an xUnit test project and the problem I’m having is that the System.IO methods start pointing to the test project bin folder. I need a permanent but clean way of referencing that Configuration file in the console app or anywhere else. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct as it does show me how to get to the root of a project, but I think I'll have to open a new question that more explicitly outlines the problems with my test project.